# Neural Network ValueError: shapes (2115,13) and (1,) not aligned: 13 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

Tags: python, neural-network, dimension

i am quite helpless right now, although i searched for the answer for a couple of days, i couldn't find an appropriate one. I also saw, that similar questions were asked, but i still couldn't find a solution for my dimension problem.

My aim is to predict the ticket price for cinemas. I splitted the data in training and test data.
Everything until the "create neural network" part goes well.
I am a beginner. Please help!

ValueError: shapes (8457,13) and (1,) not aligned: 13 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

```
    data_perc= data_filtered.head(int(len(data_filtered)*(10/100)))

y=data_perc.ticket_price
x=data_perc.drop('ticket_price',axis=1) # 1=colums und 0=rows

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)
x_train.head()
x_train.shape


inputs = x_train
outputs = y_train

class NeuralNetwork:

    # intialize variables in class
    def __init__(self, inputs, outputs):
        self.inputs  = inputs
        self.outputs = outputs
        # initialize weights as .50 for simplicity
        self.weights = np.array([.50])
        self.error_history = []
        self.epoch_list = []

    #activation function ==> S(x) = 1/1+e^(-x)
    def sigmoid(self, x, deriv=False):
        if deriv == True:
            return x * (1 - x)
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    # data will flow through the neural network.
    def feed_forward(self):
        self.hidden = self.sigmoid(np.squeeze(np.dot(self.inputs, self.weights)))

    # going backwards through the network to update weights
    def backpropagation(self):
        self.error  = self.outputs - self.hidden
        delta = self.error * self.sigmoid(self.hidden, deriv=True)
        self.weights += np.dot(self.inputs.T, delta)

    # train the neural net for 25,000 iterations
    def train(self, epochs=25000):
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            # flow forward and produce an output
            self.feed_forward()
            # go back though the network to make corrections based on the output
            self.backpropagation()    
            # keep track of the error history over each epoch
            self.error_history.append(np.average(np.abs(self.error)))
            self.epoch_list.append(epoch)

    # function to predict output on new and unseen input data                               
    def predict(self, new_input):
        prediction = self.sigmoid(np.dot(new_input, self.weights))
        return prediction

# create neural network   
NN = NeuralNetwork(inputs, outputs)
# train neural network
NN.train()
```

Comment: `self.weights = np.array([.50])` is an array with _one_ number, of shape `(1,)`, as the error message is saying. Are the weights really supposed to be _one_ number?

Comment: @ForceBru actually i am not quite sure about the weights. I also tried: self.weights = np.array([[.50], [.50], [.50],[.50], [.50], [.50],[.50], [.50], [.50], [.50], [.50], [.50],[.50]]), 13 times, because i work with 13 variables in the input, but then i get the following error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. Maybe you have a suggestion? Thank you for your time and fast response!